# regular expression lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match text then any number using python re regular expression except when the text is certain words. e.g.

```
# import re
import re
# this match expression is intended to match any alphanumerical word followed by any number unless the first alphanumerical word ends with either germany or france. 
match = r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[\s]{1,}(?<!france)(?<!germany)[0-9]{1,}'

re.findall( match, 'alphanumerical1234text  12312442')
>>>['alphanumerical1234text  12312442'] # this is correct

re.findall( match, 'alphanumerical1234text germany 12312442')
>>> ['germany 12312442'] # this shouldn't return anything 

re.findall( match, 'alphanumerical1234textgermany 12312442')
>>>['alphanumerical1234textgermany 12312442'] # this shouldn't return anything

re.findall( match, 'alphanumerical1234text france 12312442')
>>>['france 12312442'] # this shouldn't return anything

re.findall( match, 'alphanumerical1234textfrance 12312442')
>>>['alphanumerical1234textfrance 12312442'] # this shouldn't return anything
```

any idea how to build this regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to put the lookbehind before the space. `…\s(?<!france)` is equivalent to `…\s`, because anything that ends with a space cannot also end with an “e”.

```
r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<!france)(?<!germany)\s+[0-9]+'
```

Comment: @Cobry: Sorry, fixed the `|`. Moving the assertions behind the space doesn’t affect what’s captured, though.

Comment: how would it work if i want the lookbehind to skip and white space r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+(?<!france)(?<!germany)\s+[0-9]+'

Comment: @Cobry: Why do you want to do that? Does this solution not work?

Comment: it works, but actually the implementation is a little bit complex than that. the code i am building must build regular expression on demand to match some addresses with complex zipcodes and states matching with zipcodes ...

Comment: @Cobry: So where does the problem come in? Maybe you can edit that into your question.